# Use bitwise AND with string on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I want use bitwise operator "&" with string like that :

```
 raw_counter_int = raw_counter.to_i
 raw_counter_bin = raw_counter_int.to_s(2)
 u = (2**62 + 2**63)
 k = u.to_s(2)
 r =  raw_counter_bin & k
 @counter_msg = r
```

but when I run my application I've this error message :

```
undefined method `&' for "10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000":String
```

How I can use this operator "&" with raw_counter_int and u which are converted in binary ?

I try with this: 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 (64 bits) to
 take bytes between the third bytes and the 10th bytes. So I want do a
 bitwise "&" with 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 & 0011 1111
 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 to take just this : 00 0000 10

Comment: Don't need string conversion here `raw_counter_int.to_s(2)` I think.

Comment: Well, you convert it into a string, what do you expect? `&` works on numbers, not strings. It's already an integer, just use `&`.

Comment: Why ? When I delete .to_s(2) on raw_counter_bin and k, I've that 0, so I do 652144440 & (2**62 + 2**63) and I want do 10000000000000000000 000000000000000000000000000000000000 & 1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: I try with this: 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 (64 bits) to take bytes between the third bytes and the 10th bytes. So I want do a bitwise AND with 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 & 0011 1111 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 to take just this : 00 0000 10

Comment: One bug I found, not related to this. But related to *bit-wise* operation https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/85756

Comment: `(12345678987654321 & 98765432123456789).to_s(2)` works.. But for example `123434 & (2**62 + 2**63).to_s(2)` not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try with this: 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 (64 bits) to
>   take bytes between the third bytes and the 10th bytes. So I want do a
>   bitwise "&" with 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 & 0011 1111
>   1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 to take just this : 00 0000 10

Let's do it:

```
("00000000100000000000000000000000".to_i(2) & "00111111110000000000000000000000".to_i(2)).to_s(2)
=> "100000000000000000000000"
```

Which is exactly what is expected! The number shown in the error (`"10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`) is `2^56`, which, when using bitwise AND with it and `2^62+2^63` is *expected* to give you a zero result...

I suggest you check your input again, and trust ruby's `&` to do the job...